# the points, where the function is discontinuous

Tags: calculus

How can I find the points where is this function is discontinuous?

$$f:[0,\infty[^2\to\mathbb R,\quad f(x,y):=\begin{cases}x/y&\text{for }y>x,\\y/x&\text{for }x>y,\\1&\text{for }y=x\end{cases}$$

If I try to define the points with 2 sequences so that $x_n\to1$ and $y_n\to1$, I get that this function is continuous. But it's not true, because I plotted this function in WolframMatematica.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is continuous. Unless you count the edges where you get discontinuities due to division by zero, the function should be continuous since your domain is bounded to $[0,\infty]$. Could you send a link of your plot and where it's discontinuous (if that's possible)?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino sure. https://ibb.co/xgkz5DK . But somebody said, that its continuous. That WolframMatematica ignored the domain. Ok, but how can I prove it pure 
mathematically, can u give me advice?

Comment: Saying you tried $x_n\to1$, $y_n\to1$ only shows it's continuous _at_ $(1,1)$. It **is** continuous at that point (but not at every point).

Comment: @hyper-neutrino the points we "count" are exactly the ones in the domain, which is as you note given explicitly. It's not continuous at every  point of the domain.

Comment: Take the sequence $x_n= n^{-1}$ and $y_n:= 2 x_n$, what can you say for $f(x_n,y_n)$ ?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes. But how can I prove, that its continuous on whole domain, not only at that point?

Comment: @Leo that f(x_n,y_n)=1/2

Comment: @nikibiki You can show continuity at *most* points by showing that $f(x, y) = e^{-|\ln x - \ln y|}$ for $x, y > 0$. This is a composition of continuous functions. You'll have to deal with the boundary cases ($x = 0$ and/or $y = 0$) separately.

Comment: @nikibiki Now what is the limit value when $n$ tends to infinity, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n, y_n)$ ? Does it equal $f(0,0)$ ? What can you conclude ?

Comment: @Leo no. f(0,0) = 1. and this lim is equal to 1/2. thus is this function at the point (0,0) discontinuous. right?

Comment: @nikibiki exactly, I’ll let you navigate the other comments to see the rest of the story as I don’t have time right now to post a full answer. If no one post one I’ll maybe add one later

Comment: @Leo ok) thank u!

Comment: @hyper-neutrino hello! U was right!!!! Its continuous on domain [0,R]. I forgot about this important moment. Sorry. Ich have exactly this domain. But how can I prove it?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino my idea, check the point with x=y with two sequences. Because x/y and y/x as rational functions are continuous. I think the problem is x>y and y<x, I have to prove this point, right?

Comment: @Leo Thank u for so detailed response. One moment, case with x=y=0 cant be, because if x=0, y has to be strickly greater, the same situation if y=0, isn't? Thank u so much !

Comment: @nikibiki could you clarify your question? If $x\neq y$ and $x=0$ then yes, $y$ has to be strictly greater, same if we interchange the variables

Comment: @Leo I'm sorry, I'm idiot) U wrote everything right. Thank u!

Comment: @TheoBendit thank u so much!

Answer (score 3):

Let us $f\,:\,[0,+\infty)^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function you defined above.
We will look at the function behavior, first when $x\neq0$ and $y\neq 0$, then when either $x=0$ or $y=0$, and last when $x=0=y$.

### Case $x,y>0$

On the domain $(0,+\infty)^2$, $f$ is continuous.
As said by @theo-bendit we can, on this domain rewrite $f$ as an exponential.
Let suppose $x\geq y>0$, then
$$
f(x,y)= \frac{y}{x} = \frac{e^{\log y}}{e^{\log x}} = e^{\log y - \log x}
$$
Same reasoning if $y\geq x>0$ gets us that on the restricted domain
$$
f(x,y) = e^{-|\log(x)- \log(y)|}
$$
This is a composition of continuous function meaning that $f$ is continuous on this restriction.

### Case $x=0$ or $y=0$

What happen now when we allow either $x$ of $y$ to be 0?
Since the function is symmetric I will suppose w.l.o.g. that $x>y = 0$.
Take any sequence $x_n\to x > 0$, and $y_n \to 0$.
We since $x_n\to c>0$ and $y_n\to 0$, we can choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ sufficently large such that $\forall n\geq N$, we have $x_n > y_n$.
I will only look at this part of the sequence now.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n, y_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{y_n}{x_n} \overset{(\star)}{=}\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n}{\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n} = \frac{0}{c} = f(c, 0) =  f\Big(\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n, y_n)\Big)
$$
Which mean that $f$ is continuous at every point in $[0,+\infty)^2 \setminus (0,0)$.
We get $(\star)$ only because the limit of $x_n$ is not 0, and that both limits are defined (by hypothesis).

Quick note: You can also use this method to show that there is no discontinuity on the line $x=y$ (expected when $x=y=0$).
Take some point $c$ and two sequences $x_n\to c$, $y_n\to c$, then the limit of the ratio will always be 1.

### Case $x=y=0$

Now we can show that $f$ is **not** continuous at $(0,0)$.
To show this it suffice to take a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $\lim f(x_n,y_n) \neq f\big(\lim\; (x_n,y_n)\big)$.

Take $x_n := n^{-1}$ and $y_n:= 2\cdot x_n$, then $y_n \to 0$ and $x_n\to 0$.
Moreover $y_n > x_n$, meaning
$$
f(x_n,y_n) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Clearly
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n,y_n) = \frac{1}{2}\neq 1 = f(0,0) = f\Big(\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n, y_n) \Big)
$$

Below are some plot and the Mathematica code to generate them.

### Extras

[image: Plot of the function and some sequences]

In blue you have the trajectory of the sequence I defined above, and I added the trajectory of another sequence:
$$
x_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\quad y_n = \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
This sequence also converges to $(0,0)$ but the ratio is equal to $1=f(0,0)$ in the limit.
It shows that not every sequence will prove that $f$ has a discontinuity at $(0,0)$, and that you have to find the right ones.

Note that the dip you see on the line $x=y$ when going close to $(0,0)$ is purely graphical, you can play with the code and zoom on this domain and you will see that the graph basically looks the same.
Same thing for the hole you see on the line $x=y$, it is just graphical.

### Mathematica code

```
f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1, x == y}, {x/y, y > x}, {y/x, x > y}}]
p1 := Plot3D[{f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];
p2 := ParametricPlot3D[{1/n, 2/n, 1/2}, {n, 0.2, 100}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
p3 := ParametricPlot3D[{1/(n + 1)^2, 1/n^2, n^2/(n + 1)^2}, {n, 0.3, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[p1, p2, p3]
```